Link between Carathéodory's criterion and commutation in an orthomodular lattice?
In the theory of outer measures, Carathéodory's criterion constructs from an outer measure $\mu^*$ on $X$ a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $X$, on which the restriction of $\mu^*$ is a measure.
A set $A \subseteq X$ is in $\Sigma$ if and only if
$$ \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \setminus A) \quad \text{for all $E \subseteq X$.} $$
In an orthomodular lattice $L$, elements $p,q \in L$ commute if
$$ p = (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge q^\perp) \text. $$
This is a symmetric relation; in fact an orthocomplemented lattice is orthomodular if and only if this relation is symmetric.
We can say that an element of $L$ is central if it commutes with all elements of $L$.
If $L$ is for example the orthomodular lattice of projections of a von Neumann alegbra, the central elements of $L$ are the central projections.
In this context, the orthocomplement of $q \in L$ is $q^\perp = 1-q$, and
$$ (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge q^\perp) = (p \cap q) + (p \cap q^\perp) \text, $$
where $+$ is the operator sum and $p \cap q$ is the orthogonal projection onto the intersection of the ranges of $p$ and $q$.
We could thus say that the Carathéodory $\sigma$-algebra consists of all $A \subseteq X$ which are “central through $\mu^*$”.
Is there a more intricate structure to the connection between these notions?

I think you have $A$ and $E$ backwards in the statement of Carathéodory's criterion.
